# Help estimating an exponential sum

Tags: nt.number-theory

If $\sum_{p\mid n} 1=\omega(n)$, with $1\leq t\leq q-1$ an integer, and $q$ an arbitrary prime.

Then what known asymptotics or bounds can be obtained for $\sum_{n\leq x}e^{2\pi i t\omega(n)/q}$

More specifically I am looking for an estimate on,

$$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{t=1}^{p-1}e^{2\pi i t \omega(n)/p}$$

I am aware that for a fixed constant $c$ that , $e^{c\omega(n)}$ is multiplicative if that helps at all, so that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{2\pi i t\omega(n)/q}}{n^s}=\prod_{p}(1+\frac{e^{2\pi i t/q}}{p^s-1})$$

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to estimate the summatory function for $\omega(\omega(n))$.

Comment: Yes, but I would also be interested in estimates on the partial sums of $\zeta^{\omega(n)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum $\sum_{n\le x} e^{2\pi i t \omega(n)/q}$ is the sum 
of a multiplicative function whose value at a prime $p$ is 
$e^{2\pi i t/q}$.   Asymptotics for partial sums of multiplicative 
functions $f$ with $f(p)=z$, a given number, are well understood 
by work of Selberg and Delange.  The answer is 
$$ 
\sim C x (\log x)^{z-1}/\Gamma(z), 
$$ 
where $C = C(f)$ is the 
limiting value of  $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)/n^s) \zeta(s)^{-z}$ as $s\to 1$, and 
$\Gamma(z)$ is the usual $\Gamma$ function.

See Selberg's paper Note on a paper of L.G. Sathe; or Tenenbaum's book on 
analytic and probabilistic number theory for more on this topic.

One can also understand the sum of $\omega(\omega(n))$ for $n\le x$ more directly. 
Almost all numbers up to $x$ have about $\log \log x$ prime factors (up to deviations of 
about $\sqrt{\log \log x}$), and then a number of size $\log \log x$ would have 
about $\log \log \log \log x$ prime factors.  So I would guess this answer to be 
about $x \log \log \log \log x$.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about that estimate for $\omega(\omega(n))$ for example similar heuristics wouldn't work on the sum, $$\sum_{n\leq x} \omega(d(n))=x\ln(\ln(x))+O(x)$$ Also I can't seem to find the paper, could you post a link please.

Answer (score 3):

As Lucia says, in order to estimating $\sum_{n\le x} v^{\omega(n)}$ the key phrase is Selberg-Delange method (there is a chapter about it in Tenenbaum's book "Intro to analytic and probabilistic number theory").

As far as estimating $S(x) =\sum_{n\le x} \omega(\omega(n))$ is concerned, which is what you actually want to do, it is be possible to apply a more direct approach, as Lucia also indicates. I shall elaborate on this below. (Note that this approach is more direct only on the surface, as it depends on results derived via the Selberg-Delange method.) The starting point is the identity
$$
S(x) = \sum_{r\ge1} \omega(r) \pi_r(x) ,
$$
where
$$
\pi_r(x)=\#\{n\le x: \omega(n)=r\}.
$$
Now, we know that
\begin{align*}
\pi_r(x)
&=\left( \lambda\left(\frac{r-1}{\log\log x} \right) + O\left(\frac{r}{(\log\log x)^2}\right)\right)\frac{x}{\log x} \frac{(\log\log x)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!} \\
&\asymp \frac{x}{\log x} \frac{(\log\log x)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!},
\end{align*}
uniformly for $r\le 10\log\log x$, where
$$
\lambda(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(z+1)} \prod_p\left(1+\frac{z}{p-1}\right)\left(1-\frac1p\right)^{z}
$$
(This is Theorem 4 in page 205 of Tenenbaum's book, 1995 english edition). Larger $r$ should contribute very little to $S(x)$. One can use the Hardy-Ramanujan theorem to bound their contribution, which says that 
$$
\pi_r(x) \le \frac{Ax}{\log x} \frac{(\log\log x+B)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!},
$$
for two absolute constants $A$ and $B$ (and all $r\ge1$ and $x\ge3$). So we essentially have that
\begin{align*}
S(x) 
&\sim \sum_{r\le 10\log\log x} \omega(r) \pi_r(x) \\
&\sim \sum_{r\le 10\log\log x} \omega(r) \lambda\left(\frac{r-1}{\log\log x} \right) \frac{x}{\log x} \frac{(\log\log x)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!} .
\end{align*}
Most of the contribution to this sum should come from integers $r=\log\log x+O(\sqrt{\log\log x})$ which have about $\log\log\log\log x$ prime factors. Also, for such $r$ we have that $\lambda((r-1)/\log\log x)\sim1$. The sum of $(\log\log x)^{r-1}/(r-1)!$ over such $r$ should be $\sim \log x$ (this is a baby version of the Central Limit Theorem). So it seems that $S(x)\sim x\log\log\log\log x$.

You might be able to obtain this result using your initial approach too, you have to be careful about the dependence of your estimates on $p$ though.